# Locked screen app for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create an locked screen app for Windows Phone. I know how to create Apps but i don't know how to create an locked screen.

For example, if a user opens my app, he can activate the locked screen wallpaper. Then the user can close the app, after 30 seconds the screen will lock(sleep stand of phone). On the locked screen there will be an image and information data that comes from the closed(tombstoned) app.

I checked lifecycle of a windows phone application but can not figure out how to build this?

Anyone got some articles or tutorials???

Answer (score 4):

There's a good reason why you couldn't figure it out. It's not possible, and most likely never going to be possible (which is very nice).

Comment: is it not possible for example to put an app in tombstoned mode and that after 30 secs the app(fake screen lock) will come over? Please elaborate your awnser

Comment: @apps it is a huge security issue.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Phone 8 and 7.8, you can update the lock screen with any image. Check out this detailed guide - http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8